# What integer operations can be efficiently emulated using floating point?

Tags: floating-point, integer, numerical-methods

I need to work on a processor that natively supports 16-bit integer math and 32-bit floating point operations.
Some of the algorithms that are targeting the processor require integer math accuracy that is higher than 16 bits. The most straightforward option is to emulate using 16-bit integer operations.
I noticed that some architectures support 24-bit integer math operations. I suspect this has to do with the mantissa size being 24-bits. So the floating point unit is somehow being used for the integer math.
Is it possible in some cases to make use of the floating point instructions for efficiency?

Comment: "I noticed that some architectures support 24-bit integer math operations. I suspect this has to do with the mantissa size being 24-bits." --> Various PIC24 processor support 24-bit integers because the address space and instruction width 24-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming IEEE-754 floating point, any integer with magnitude up to 2^24 is exactly representable, and all operations producing an in-range result will produce exact integer results. (You will, of course, need to manually handle rounding of division results.) For wider integer types, there are certain FP techniques (based on storing a single number as a sum of multiple floats with non-overlapping significands) but those would likely be much slower than just doing conventional multi-word arithmetic operations.